# How do you mount a hard drive in RW mode?

Tags: hard-drive

I have an external HD that, when plugged in, is accessible at: `/media/myusername/79039342-7793-4990-9eae-95ef3d4a9331`.

I figured out it's the drive called `/dev/sdb` (with a single partition in it `sdb1`).

Fine!

Thing is, it is not writeable.

If I try:

```
sudo mount -o remount,uid=1000,gid=1000,rw /dev/sdb1
```

I get:

```
/media/myusername/79039342-7793-4990-9eae-95ef3d4a9331 not mounted or bad option
```

So the question is: how do I make it writeable?

Answer (score 1):

First, when it's auto-mounted, run `mount` and look for the `/dev/sdb1` and see how it's mounted now. If there's a `ro` it's read-only, or a `rw` means you're almost done :)

And a `lsblk` is a prettier way to see if & where drives are mounted too. `sudo blkid` may show some more useful info as well, possibly about FS types.

It may be mounted rw now, but the permissions won't let you write to it. May need to `chown` to get write permissions.

Or if it is `ro`, try a basic `sudo mount -o remount,rw /dev/sdb1`, maybe it's erroring on the other options.

If that doesn't work, then my only other idea now is - is it a writeable filesystem? Or a ro-only system like squashfs or iso9660/cd format? `gparted` should show what partitions & FS's are what.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would unmount it.

```
umount /dev/sdb1
```

Then, I'd remount it

```
sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /home/user/driveb1 rw  0    2
```

I would then check to be sure it was remounted

```
mount
```